# How do you use Disk Utility to "restore" a Time Machine drive to another one? (Could not validate sizes, OSStatus error -50)

Tags: time-machine

This is a followup to [copying an old Time Machine backup to a newer, larger disk literally takes months, any way to speed up / make it incremental?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446835/copying-an-old-time-machine-backup-to-a-newer-larger-disk-literally-takes-month) .

tl;dr on that: I'm trying to copy a 6 TB nearly-full Time Machine disk to a new 12 TB disk and use the new disk instead. The suggestion from the above link (thanks @benwiggy): "Use Disk Utility to 'Restore' the old disk onto the new one."

So I boot into recovery mode (new Catalina upgrade), restore to the new disk from the old one, and see

Could not validate sizes - Invalid argument.
The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)

This seems to be, actually, an invalid argument error message. Any wisdom? (Is it perhaps not possible to restore onto a larger disk and that's the size-validation concern?)

Comment: I am guessing you have the old HFS+ formatted TM disk. Can you confirm?

Comment: If HFS+ you might have luck with SuperDuper as suggested here https://dancarrphotography.com/blog/2020/03/05/the-best-way-to-copy-time-machine-backups/  I can't confirm as I always start a fresh TM and keep old one until not needed. I realise that is not strictly your question.

Comment: MacOS Extended (Journaled). I believe that's HFS+. (It's a spinning-disk drive, not SSD.) I will give SuperDuper a whirl. That blog post, I think, could have been written by me. Thanks @Gilby! Will report back.